# How to structure a Bootstrap grid to contain 4 unequal size boxes

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap and would like to create a grid that looks like this:
[image]

Here is my code (which is not giving the desired result):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>foo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 border justify-content-center">
                    Area 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 border justify-content-center">
                    Area 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 border justify-content-center">
                    Area 3
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 border justify-content-center">
                    Area 4
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Currently, the grid is rendering like this:

[image]

How can I fix up my code to get the desired structure (particularly the heights)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this if you have to stick with using bootstrap. Keep in mind that can create this layout more easily just by using css grid or flexbox without bootstrap.

```css
.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
}

.left .col-12:first-of-type {
  min-height: 300px;
}

.right .col-12 {
  height: 50%;
}

.col-12 {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6 border justify-content-center">
                <div class="row left">
                  <div class="col-12 border justify-content-center">
                    <p>Area 1</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 border justify-content-center">
                    <p>Area 2</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 border justify-content-center">
                <div class="row right">
                  <div class="col-12 border justify-content-center">
                    <p>Area 3</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 border justify-content-center">
                    <p>Area 4</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are wanting a responsive grid with 4 boxes of equal-width and variable heights, to fill all available space in the rectangular container.

To do that, start with a base grid of one `.row` having two `.col-6` for the left and right half. Then make each `.col-6` a vertical flexbox container with `.d-flex.flex-column`, this allows their children to have 'flexible' heights. Then use a `div.flex-fill` for the "Area n" child containers so they will expand to fill the available height of the parent.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 border p-0 d-flex flex-column">

      <div class="border bg-primary text-white p-2 flex-fill">
        <h1>Area 1</h1>
        <p>
          Some content here to take up some space naturally. Some content here to take up some space naturally. Some content here to take up some space naturally.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="border bg-secondary text-white p-2 flex-fill">
        <h1>Area 2</h1>
        <p>
          Some content here to take up some space naturally.
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 border p-0 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="border bg-success text-white p-2 flex-fill">
        <h1>Area 3</h1>
        <p>
          Some content here.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="border bg-danger text-white p-2 flex-fill">
        <h1>Area 4</h1>
        <p>
          Some content here to take up some space naturally. Some content here to take up some space naturally.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```